# Is profitable direct arbitrage impossible with getAmountsOut?

Tags: javascript, ethereumjs, math, arbitrage, uniswapv2

I’ve run the math on a uniswap v2 arbitrage trade that looks more or less like this:

```
1) Buy X amount of token1 with Y amount of token0 on Uniswap
2) Sell equivalent amount of token1 in exchange for token0 on Sushiswap
3) Profit?
```

This method necessarily uses `getAmountsOut` which, I believe, is calculated as follows:

```
AmountOut = (AmountIn * ReservesToken1) / (ReservesToken0 + AmountIn) * (1 - fee)
```

In my calculation, fee is the typical .3%.  I’ve run around 2-3000 calculations and can’t find a single scenario where using `getAmountsOut` on both exchanges would result in a positive outcome.  Am I missing something here?

[Here’s a google sheet with some of my calculations](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-KcAPceCZ_xBCyQfVViEoPpx3js9R7NyaWUmeD1pGsM/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deep analysis, and over 300,000 mathematical scenarios run, it seems that by using `getAmountsOut` math on both exchanges it isn't IMPOSSIBLE to win, but it's highly highly unlikely.

Across those 300,000 scenarios only around 6000 were successful, resulting in a less than 2% win rate.  Better than 0, sure, but very very low nonetheless.  Looks like this isn't really a strategy that's going to work.

You can check the spreadsheet I linked in the question if you're curious to see the raw data (See J3363 for the final profit numbers).

Answer (score 0):

The methodology works, that's a valid arbitrage if the two dex pools are in a certain state. In theory, you would want one of the pairs to have a lot more liquidity/less slippage in your trading range, and a better price on the other dex. If you include UniswapV3 dexes into this mix I bet the number of opportunities increases also due to concentrated liquidity.

Arbitrage market is super competitive these days though, which is probably why you see low incidences of this working.

But the reason there are few opportunities to do this is because there are already actors constantly watching for this arbitrage.

Comment: I'm certain there are opportunities (and that there are others watching for them too).  The issue isn't so much that as it is the raw calculation of ```getAmountsOut``` on platform 1 and then again using the results on platform 2 just doesn't come out to a profitable trade in the vast majority of cases.  Then adding in slippage, fees, etc, it becomes almost impossible to find a good opportunity.  I updated the sheet with a 310K cell matrix of final result calculations.  1.96% of which were successful before including gas